# Click event not firing on checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Am I going crazy?

I can't get a click event to fire on a checkbox.

This is my JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.checkbox').on('click', function () {
            console.log('ello');
        });
    });
```

This is my php/html:

```
    <ul class="category-filters">
            <li>
                <input class="checkbox" value="Customer Service" type="checkbox">Customer Service
            </li>
            <li>
                <input class="checkbox" value="HR" type="checkbox">HR</li>
    </ul>
```

It is worth pointing out that if I change the function/method to hide then it works...

but it does not trigger a click event. I've used on and click to try this..

Is it because the class selector I'm using returns an array?

Cheer

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, since JavaScript works with the HTML received by the browser once the PHP has finished its work and sent that HTML. So, please: show the ("*[MCVE]*") HTML received by the browser, and remove the PHP - unless there's an error in the PHP?

Comment: at least say please

Comment: I did say 'please.'

Comment: Well done your mother brought you up well

Comment: show your function here .may be problem is there

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? Show your function..  Its Jquery..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the change event.

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
  alert('ello')
})
```

jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/xonecajeva/edit?html,css,js,output